# Getting properties from onClick event in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3, and I would like to know which properties can we get from events? I searched everywhere including official documentation, but cannot find anything. An example of my code is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
                    polygons[i].setMap(map);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(polygons[i], 'click', function(event) {
                    var contentString = '<b>Test polygon</b><br>' +
                    'Clicked location: <br>'+ event.latLng.lat() +
                    '<br>';
                        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

                        infoWindow.open(map);
                    });
                }
```

The polygons array has a lot of polygons I created. I can get latitude with `event.latLng.lat()`. What else can I get this way? Can I get the position of my polygon in the *polygons* array? Or any other info from it?
I know that I can get polygon vertices with `vertices = this.getPath();`...

Comment: Have you tried console.log(event) to see what properties seem to be in there?

Answer (score 1):

To set or get the polygon properties on any event just use "this" keyword in the scope the callback, this here will = to the polygon clicked.

Ex: any property or method is available like

```
this.fillColor
```

will get you back the color in type string from "this.fillColor", but it should be there before the callback executed or lets say outside the listener.

You can also set your own properties to any shape using the set method  like this

```
set("key", value); 

polygons[i].set("length", polygons[i].length);
```

Then with this.length you get it returned in the click callback

Answer (score 0):

A [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) click event returns a [PolyMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolyMouseEvent) object. Note that the "PolyMouseEvent" specific properties are only available on **editable** polys.

Documented properties:

- edge | number | The index of the edge within the path beneath the cursor when the event occurred, if the event occurred on a mid-point on an editable polygon.
- path | number | The index of the path beneath the cursor when the event occurred, if the event occurred on a vertex and the polygon is editable. Otherwise undefined.
- vertex | number | The index of the vertex beneath the cursor when the event occurred, if the event occurred on a vertex and the polyline or polygon is editable. If the event does not occur on a vertex, the value is undefined.

This object extends [MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent).

Properties

- latLng | LatLng | The latitude/longitude that was below the cursor when the event occurred.